# Hibernate @ManyToMany with extra columns

Tags: java, hibernate

So I've been trying the solutions out there to map a ManyToMany relationship with extra columns but none of them is working for me and I don't know what am I doing wrong.

The Many to Many relationship is between Patient and Disease (a Patient can have multiple diseases and a Disease can be suffered by many Patients). The time attribute means "the type of the disease" (acute, chronic...)

My classes are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="patient")
public class Patient{

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="nss")
    private String NSS;
    
    //Some attributes
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
    private Set<PatientDisease> diseases = new HashSet<PatientDisease>();
    
    //Empty constructor and constructor using fields omitted
    //Getters and setters ommited
}
```

,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="disease")
public class Disease{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "disease")
    private Set<PatientDisease> patients = new HashSet<PatientDisease>();
    
    //Constructors and getters and setters ommited for brevity
}
```

Associated class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Patient_Disease")
@IdClass(PatientDiseaseID.class)
public class PatientDisease{

    @Id 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "nssPatient", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Patient patient;
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "diseaseID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Disease disease;
    
    @Column(name="time")
    private String time;
    
    //GETTERS AND SETTERS OMMITED FOR BREVETY. Constructor NOT Needed following the example
}
```

The id class:

```
@Embeddable
public class PatientDiseaseId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Column(name = "nssPatient")
    private String patient;
    
    @Column(name = "diseaseID")
    private Integer disease;

    //getters and setters
    //hashCode and equals
}
```

My main app:

```
...
List<Diseases> diseases = sesion.createQuery("from Disease").getResultList();
            System.out.println("Diseases: ");
            for(Disease d: diseases) {
                System.out.println(d.getName());
                for(PatientDisease pd: e.getPatientDisease()) {
                    System.out.println(pd.getPatient().toString());
                }
            }
...
```

When running the main App I get the exception on line 5 (2nd for loop):
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [1] value by reflection : [class entities.PatientDisease.diseases] setter of entities.PatientDisease.diseases

I have tried some solutions here in Stack Overflow an some others that I found on the Internet, but I can't get them to work and I don't know why

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381067/could-not-set-field-value-by-reflection

Comment: Because you are using `@IdClass` you don't need to annotate `PatientDiseaseId` with `@Embedded` and `@Column`. See the Hibernate ORM documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-nonaggregated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [you are using `@IdClass`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-nonaggregated) you don't need to annotate `PatientDiseaseId` with `@Embedded` and `@Column`.  And you have to refer to the entities.

This is what it should look like:

```
public class PatientDiseaseId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private Patient patient;
    
    private Disease disease;

    //getters and setters
    //hashCode and equals
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to maintain the order of the list, you can include `@OrderColumn` on the "owning" side of the relationship.

If you need more than that you create and `@Embeddable` class to use as a key and associate the entities as a map.

The Key Class

- `equals()` and `hashCode()` must always be overridden for this use
- `Comparable` only needs to be implemented if you want to use a `SortedMap`

  ```
    @Embeddable
    public class PatientDiseaseKey implements Comparable<PatientDiseaseKey > {
    private Integer order;
    private String time;
    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@Nonnull PatientDiseaseKey k) {
        return Integer.compare(this.order, k.order);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof PatientDiseaseKey)) {
            return false;
        }
        PatientDiseaseKey that = (PatientDiseaseKey) o;
        return getTime() == that.getTime() && Objects.equals(getOrder(), that.getOrder());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getOrder(), getTime());
    }
  ```

  }

Patients

```
@ManyToMany // a patient can't have multiple diseases with the same key
@JoinTable(
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "disease_id"))
@AttributeOverride(name = "key.time", column = @Column(name = "disease_time"))
@AttributeOverride(name = "key.order", column = @Column(name = "disease_order"))
@SortNatural
private SortedMap<PatientDiseaseKey, Disease> diseases = new TreeMap<>();
```

Disease

```
@ManyToMany// necessary for orphanRemoval
@JoinTable(
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "disease_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id"))
@AttributeOverride(name = "key.time", column = @Column(name = "disease_time"))
@AttributeOverride(name = "key.order", column = @Column(name = "disease_order"))
@SortNatural
private SortedMap<PatientDiseaseKey, Patient> patients = new TreeMap<>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "diseases") // a disease could have many patients with the same key, this gets all patients, regardless of key
private List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<>();
```

Both sides must appear as owning so that you can get the appropriate `orphanRemoval` behaviour, which is not available on `@ManyToMany`

And as always. do a `map.clear()` and `map.putAll(...)` to update the associations.